# PHP: Is it possible to execute a MySQL statement to create a DATABASE even though I am already connected to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been wondering if it's possible to create a new database using mysqli_query() even though I'm already connected to my database?

```
$create_new_db = mysqli_query($user_conn, "CREATE DATABASE sample_db");

if($create_new_db) {
echo 'new database has been created';
} else {
echo 'Error while creating new database.';
}
```

my variable $user_conn has a database connection named db_maindb. So is it still possible to create a new database when I'm connected to my db_maindb database?

Comment: if your connected  user have proper grant .. yes .. you can execute a create statement

Comment: thanks for the response sir. but can you give me an example on how to do it?

Comment: I have posted  a basic answer .. change the $servername, $username, $password  with your real value ..

Comment: MySQL server doesn't allow database creation from sql command. It's not recommended, unless you have an emergency need to do so then you should consider allowing this type of DATABASE creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you have in you code  ..

assuming you can connect to an existing database and your connected  user has grant for create database  you can

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE sample_db";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```